# Pygame not working properly on ubuntu

Tags: python, pygame

My pygame code

```
bif="images.jpg"
mif="point.png"
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)
background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
mouse_c=pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()
while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
```

Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 8, in <module>
    background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file
```

The Same Code Works on different machine but doesn't works on my machine .

Can anyone please help me to solve that problem

How Can I uninstall whole python from my ubuntu machine and than reinstall.

Comment: Have you considered using a virtualenv?

Comment: well you are loading a png and a jpg file, no wonder there is an error.

Comment: Check whether `pygame.image.get_extended()` returns `True`. Source: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski This Code Works on Different Machine.

Comment: You might want to either try putting the image in a different format or copying the image from a machine that works without editing it.

Comment: yes I tried it.It doesn't worked

Comment: By the way I'm not sure but I don't think you need to import pygame.locals. That is automatically imported when you import pygame.

Answer (score 1):

Pygame usually loads png files. Several other filetypes will not work. Jpeg will not always be supported. If you want to be absolutely sure that the image will load properly, use an uncompressed bitmap format, but png should work. You could convert the jpg file to png format in any number of ways, for example using an image editor to save it in a different format, or just downloading format conversion software online. If you load png files only, there will be no error.